# How to plot the actual price at which a moving average crosses

Tags: pine-script

I want to be able to capture the actual price at the time that the moving averages cross. 
I know that the MA cross price is always different to the actual price at the time of the cross as MA's are lagging indicators. 
I know there are built in variables for close, high, low, etc. but is there a built in variable for the actual tick price? 
Or is there a work around method to get this price? 
A possible solution would to get the close from a lower time frame. For example, if working with a an MA crossing on the daily, then how could you code getting the close from a lower time frame?
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is what I have tried so far:

// I am working on a daily chart

cond1 = crossover(sma(close, 7), sma(close, 21))

CurrentPrice = security(ticker, "1", close)

plot((cond1 ? CurrentPrice: na),style=circles, color=green, transp=transp)

Unfortunately this does not plot the green circle at the 1-minute close price on the daily chart. But rather at some other price which I don't how is calculated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to pinescript, but I think I have something that might help.  Research the "valuewhen" function.  In the case below, when the MA_9 crosses under the MA_12 the low of the bar will the printed when the condition occurs. The condition is defined in the beginning of the valuewhen function, what you want to print (high/low/close or another indicator even) is specified near the end of the valuewhen function.  In the case below, when the condition occurs the low value will be plotted.  You may want to change the "low" at the end of the valuewhen to "close" as most people plot their moving averages on the close.  Remember that once you've created the valuewhen, it still needs to be plotted/printed as a label, etc.
Hope this helps.

//@version=4
study("ValueWhen")

MA_9 = sma(close, 9)

MA_12 = sma(close, 12)

MA_Cross    = valuewhen(crossunder(MA_9, MA_12), low, 0)

plot(MA_Cross)

Comment: no unfortunately this does not work, because the valuewhen function returns the "close" or "low" of the current time frame. Hence if you are on a daily chart, and the cross occurs, it will show the close of the daily candle, but not the actual price at the time that the cross happened.
I have sort of found a work around for this but it is not very elegant. Here:

CurrentPrice = security(ticker, "1", ohlc4) 

So if you are working on a daily chart, this will give you the value of the current 1 minute ohlc4 bar.

Comment: Can you clarify which time frame the chart is plotted on, and which time frame you'd like to capture the MA cross on?
One option would be to create a new security from the "non-plotted" time frame and use the close of that security in place of the close in my suggestion.  
Another option is to synthesize the MA's into the time frame you're using.  I've had success doing this, and it avoids the creation of addt'l securities (Pine limits to 40).  See 2nd post for details...

Comment: To synthesize an MA you simply take the number of minutes of the plotted time frame divided into the number of minutes time frame you want to synthesize from, then take that number and multiply it by the periods in your MA.  For example, say you want to synth a 50 period MA from an hourly chart on a 15 minute chart.  60/15 = 4.  4 x the 50 period MA gives you a 200 periods.  So, sma(close,200) on a 15 minute chart = a sma(close,50) on an hourly chart.  'not sure how well this would work plotting on a smaller time frame though.  'just a thought.  sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I am working on a daily chart and I have two MA on this daily chart. Now, when the two MA's cross on the daily chart, I want to know what is the ticker price at that time. 
I know I can see the price where the MA's crossed, but because MA's are lagging, the actual ticker price at the time of the cross is different and that is what I would like to know. 
E.G. when the MA cross happens on the daily chart, I would like to know the ticker price at that exact minute if possible. 
I have tried the security function, but it does not give the accurate reading. 
Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Hmmm, wish I was more fluent in pinescript so I could help more.  So the chart's plot is the same time frame that the moving averages are being plotted on?  I believe alerts will print intrabar (before a bar closes).  If an alert would be acceptable to you, making a simple alert for the MA cross might work.  In the alert message body you can have it print the last value. A label (if they print intrabar, I'm  not sure about this) could also be created for the initial crossing value.  Time can be measured down to milliseconds. Factoring time may allow an alert to be printed w/a very recent x.

Comment: Using the chart's replay feature may allow testing to see if a possible remedy prints intrabar.

Comment: can alerts print the current price on the chart? Could you provide some code on how you could do this?

Comment: I'm testing it now.  I am getting intrabar alerts if the alert is set to trigger when the MA's equal each other, but I'm not sure if they'll trigger during an MA crossing since they need to reference the previous bar.  But, I think if we synthesize the MA from a smaller time frame we can get pretty close.  See next post for the code.  And yes to print the price it the message.  in the panel for the settings for the alert near the bottom enter {{close}} in the message.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you're pulling data from a higher time frame and the alert conditions are barely met, you can get false triggers since the price/condition in the larger time frame hasn't closed yet and may change before closing.  This is a perennial prob when using multiple time frames.  I had a better idea than synthesizing...  Plot this on a 1 minute chart (that's the smallest time frame you can use when using the security function).  Try this on "CIR" as it's had a recent 7 x 21 cross on the Daily.  This should trigger the 1st minute that the Daily MA's cross.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Alert: 7x21 Daily Time Frame", overlay=true)

MA_7   = sma(close,7)
MA_21   = sma(close,21)

//  Time frame change to Daily
MA_7_Daily  = security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', MA_7, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
MA_21_Daily = security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', MA_21,lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

//  (I like to visually verify my code.  plots are not necessary for the alerts)
plot(MA_7_Daily, color = color.lime)
plot(MA_21_Daily, color = color.red)

alertcondition(MA_7_Daily[1] <= MA_21_Daily[1] and MA_7_Daily >= MA_21_Daily, message = "Daily Moving Ave 7 x 21 Long")
alertcondition(MA_7_Daily[1] >= MA_21_Daily[1] and MA_7_Daily <= MA_21_Daily, message = "Daily Moving Ave 7 x 21 Short")
```

Comment: ...you can also take the code and daily info and use it in a valuewhen to create a label on the 1 minute chart if you want a visual for the price....

Comment: To clarify what I was wanting to get is:

"to plot a dot symbol on the daily chart at the price when the daily MA cross condition is FIRST met, and not any subsequent times within the current daily bar"
.
So plotting the price on the minute chart is not what I was after. It was the opposite, I wanted the price from the minute chart to be plotted on the daily, and also to be only plotted on the first occurrence within the current daily bar/candle.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I think it might be a lost cause. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing a lot of research on this I have come to a realisation that it may not be possible.

To clarify what I was wanting to get is:

"to plot a dot symbol on the daily chart at the price when the daily MA cross condition is FIRST met, and not any subsequent times within the current daily bar"

Unfortunately this is most likely not possible, as the cross condition can occur multiple times per current daily bar and so far I have not found any way to just capture the first instance of the condition being met per bar (or as it is also know as "Once Per Bar").

I have spoken with a couple of experienced pine coders and they also said they have never seen anything like this before...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
MA_7 = sma(close, 7)

MA_21 = sma(close, 21)

MA_Cross = (MA_7[1] < MA_21[1]) and (MA_7 > MA_21)

plot(MA_Cross and (not MA_Cross[1]),style=circles, color=green, transp=transp)
```